# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error in ProM process mining software during csv file import

Tags: java, macos, process-mining

I have installed ProM 6.12 process mining software on my Mac M1, and followed the steps listed here: https://promtools.org/prom-6-12/ . Java version is 19.0.2. On trying to import a csv file, I get the the following error:

**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

This is what the console prints:

```
Start plug-in Import a CSV file and convert it to XES
-------- The following exception was logged by the framework: 
         The exception was probalby handled properly. 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:613)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.ProMFuture.get(ProMFuture.java:119)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.impl.PluginExecutionResultImpl.synchronize(PluginExecutionResultImpl.java:106)
    at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.hub.ProMResourceManager.importResourceNotInEDT(ProMResourceManager.java:585)
    at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.hub.ProMResourceManager.access$200(ProMResourceManager.java:58)
    at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.hub.ProMResourceManager$10.run(ProMResourceManager.java:554)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.impl.PluginDescriptorImpl.execute(PluginDescriptorImpl.java:331)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.impl.AbstractPluginDescriptor$1.doInBackground(AbstractPluginDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.ProMFuture$1.doInBackground(ProMFuture.java:56)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/univocity/parsers/common/TextParsingException
    at org.processmining.log.csvimport.CSVImportPluginUnivocity.importFromStream(CSVImportPluginUnivocity.java:28)
    at org.processmining.log.csvimport.CSVImportPluginUnivocity.importFromStream(CSVImportPluginUnivocity.java:20)
    at org.processmining.framework.abstractplugins.AbstractImportPlugin.importFile(AbstractImportPlugin.java:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 14 more
--------------------------------------------------------------
-------- The following exception was logged by the framework: 
         The exception was probalby handled properly. 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:613)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.ProMFuture.get(ProMFuture.java:119)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.impl.AbstractPluginDescriptor$1.done(AbstractPluginDescriptor.java:193)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.ProMFuture$1.done(ProMFuture.java:66)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:750)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:848)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:112)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:858)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:311)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:243)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:191)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:236)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1080)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:881)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:677)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:648)
    at org.processmining.contexts.uitopia.hub.ProMResourceManager$12.run(ProMResourceManager.java:600)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.impl.PluginDescriptorImpl.execute(PluginDescriptorImpl.java:331)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.impl.AbstractPluginDescriptor$1.doInBackground(AbstractPluginDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.processmining.framework.plugin.ProMFuture$1.doInBackground(ProMFuture.java:56)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/univocity/parsers/common/TextParsingException
    at org.processmining.log.csvimport.CSVImportPluginUnivocity.importFromStream(CSVImportPluginUnivocity.java:28)
    at org.processmining.log.csvimport.CSVImportPluginUnivocity.importFromStream(CSVImportPluginUnivocity.java:20)
    at org.processmining.framework.abstractplugins.AbstractImportPlugin.importFile(AbstractImportPlugin.java:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 14 more
```

Did anyone face this issue? Can someone help me with it?

I tried removing the XES packages from the ProM packpage manager and reinstalled them, following the cue of this particular solution: https://promforum.win.tue.nl/discussion/1298/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception . It did nothing for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was finally resolved by rolling back the Java version to version 8. More details are available on this [link](https://promforum.win.tue.nl/discussion/1554/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-error-in-prom-6-12-during-csv-file-import#latest).